# Javascript/Angular Basics - Reading a simple value from the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[I have this console.log CLICK THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQrTE.png)

[image]

And I need to change the port attribute. How do I access and change this value?

My current code

```
  createInteractionConfig = function () {
            interactionConfig = $injector.get('InteractionConfig');
            console.log(interactionConfig);
            interactionConfig.addAttribute(???? what now ????)
        };
```

Edit: On Chrome it says this path `.addAttribute["[[Scopes]]"]["0"].config.port` but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
createInteractionConfig = function () {
    interactionConfig = $injector.get('InteractionConfig');
    interactionConfig[0].config.port = 80;
};
```